# Second Activity Closes After Screen Changes Orientation. [Mono Android]

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin.android, screen-orientation, android-orientation

Hello Stack Overflow,

### Problem

When I run my first (main) android activity and change the screen orientation,
the app works normally and I can keep changing the orientation
and it still works.

When I click a button on the first activity to go to the second activity,
the screen changes and everything loads fine and I scroll up and down (everything seems fine)

However, when I switch orientation now (on the second activity), the activity closes out with no log error and reverts back to the first activity.

So my question is how do I retain the ability to switch screen orientation and not have my second activity close? Not sure what is causing this. I've read that whenever your screen orientation changes, it has to destroy and recreate the activity. But if it is working on the first activity, then why is it not working on the second one?

Here's the first activity code:

```
    [Activity(Label = "FishinTales: Main Menu", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class Activity_View_MainMenu : Activity
{
    #region Components
    private Model n_model;
    private GridView n_mainMenuGridView;
    #endregion

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        /*
            Load data using if statements. Load serializeable if no settings file.
            Or create new and test if it is accurately passing the custom class to another activity.
        */
        if (((MyApp) this.ApplicationContext).FishingData == null)
        {
            ((MyApp) this.ApplicationContext).LoadFishinTales();
            this.n_model = ((MyApp) this.ApplicationContext).FishingData;
        }
        else
        {
            this.n_model = ((MyApp) this.ApplicationContext).FishingData;
        }


        // Set our view from the "View_MainMenu" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.View_MainMenu);

        this.n_mainMenuGridView = FindViewById<GridView> (Resource.Id.xml_mainMenuGridView);
        this.n_mainMenuGridView.SetNumColumns(2);
        this.n_mainMenuGridView.Adapter = new MainMenuGridAdapter (this);

        this.n_mainMenuGridView.ItemClick += (o, e) => {
            if (e.Position == 0)
            {
                // Navigate to Fish Species
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity_View_FishSpecies));
                this.StartActivityForResult(intent, RequestCodes.View_FishSpecies);
            }
            else if (e.Position == 1)
            {
                // Navigate to My Favorite Spots
                Toast.MakeText(this, "TODO: Navigate to My Favorite Sports", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                //Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(View_MyFavoriteSpots));
                //this.StartActivityForResult(intent, RequestCodes.View_MyFavoriteSpots);
            }
            else if (e.Position == 2)
            {
                // Navigate to My Season
                Toast.MakeText(this, "TODO: Navigate to My Season", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                //Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(View_MySeason));
                //this.StartActivityForResult(intent, RequestCodes.View_MySeason);
            }
            else if (e.Position == 3)
            {
                // Navigate to Inventory
                Toast.MakeText(this, "TODO: Navigate to Inventory", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                //Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(View_Inventory));
                //this.StartActivityForResult(intent, RequestCodes.View_Inventory);
            }
            else if (e.Position == 4)
            {
                // Navigate to Fishing News
                Toast.MakeText(this, "TODO: Navigate to Fishing News", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                //Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(View_FishingNews));
                //this.StartActivityForResult(intent, RequestCodes.View_FishingNews);
            }
            else if (e.Position == 5)
            {
                // Navigate to Settings
                Toast.MakeText(this, "TODO: Navigate to Settings", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                //Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(View_Settings));
                //this.StartActivityForResult(intent, RequestCodes.View_Settings);
            }
            else
            {
                // Invalid Response
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Invalid Menu Selection", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        };
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        // Possibly save data after activity result.?.
    }
}
```

And here's an image of my first activity (the one that changes orientation with no problem):

[image: First Activity - Main Menu]

Here's the second activity code:

```
    [Activity(Label = "FishinTales: Fish Species")]
public class Activity_View_FishSpecies : Activity
{
    #region Components
    private Model n_model;
    private ListView n_fishSpeciesListView;
    #endregion

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Get Application Global Model
        this.n_model = ((MyApp) this.ApplicationContext).FishingData;

        // Set our view from the "View_FishSpecies" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.View_FishSpecies);

        this.n_fishSpeciesListView = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.xml_fishSpeciesListView);
        this.n_fishSpeciesListView.Adapter = new FishSpeciesListAdapter (this.ApplicationContext, this.n_model.SpecieManager.Species);
    }
}
```

And here's an image of my second activity (the one that closes after I try to set it to landscape orientation by tilting my phone):

[image: Second Activity - Fish Species List]

Any idea of why this is happening and even better, what would be a good work around for this case? Keep in mind I do not wish the screen to stay a certain orientation. I would like it if the user could switch between the two, without it closing on them. Thanks for reading and your help.

Comment: post logcat results also when your application is crashing

Comment: I don't believe it is necessarily crashing, I believe it is closing. There are no errors listed or I would have added them to the Post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in Mainfest xmml for your second activity

```
<activity android:name="com.package.SecondActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

Comment: Still closes. I added <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/> to the manifest and now when testing on my phone I get an java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget(Heap Size=6855KB, Allocated=3089KB, Bitmap Size=26666KB). However I built an image cache into my custom listview for fish species to remember the images. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing your problem, and for me second activity is not closed, but properly rotated when I tilt the phone. But of course, I don't have your layout and images. So looks like the problem is not in code you posted, but somewhere else.
Most probably you have space issues (I also faced memory problems when working with images). To check this, try commenting out an adapter, or code in adapter that loads images.
In my case, I had to resise the images to keep them small.
Also, code of adapter may be helpful.
Hope this helps.